# SQLite query crashing only for certain column - Failed to read row 0, column -1

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite method that returns an entire column in String[] form.  It crashes only with a single column.  I can substitute other columns and it works fine. Here is the method.

```
public String[] getLocationColumn(){
   ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   String[] column = { KEY_LOCATION };
   db.beginTransaction();
   try{
       Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_TRAILS, column, null, null, null, null, null);
       if (c != null && c.getCount() != 0){
           c.moveToFirst();
           while (!c.isAfterLast()){
               arrayList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION)));
               c.moveToNext();
           }
           c.close();
           db.setTransactionSuccessful();
       }
   }finally{
       db.endTransaction();
   }
   return arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
 }
```

and here is the error I get.

> 02-10 19:57:40.674 23786-23786/com.xxxx.xxxx E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 24 rows, 1 columns.

To repeat, I can substitute, for example KEY_NAME instead of KEY_LOCATION and it works fine.

UPDATE
I've just ran on an emulator (instead of actual phone and it works fine).  It seems to limited to a single column on my phone.

Here's more of the log (with the dumpCursor as suggested by @Mike)

> 02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out: }
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out: 1 {
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out:    location=Collegedale, Tennessee
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out: }
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out: 2 {
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out:    location=Harrison, Tennessee
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out: }
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx I/System.out: <<<<<
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 24 rows, 1 columns.
>   02-10 21:06:10.384 23480-23480/com.xxxx D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

Comment: What's the value of `KEY_LOCATION`?

Comment: City, state....  for example   Madison, Wisconsin

Comment: I meant the value of the `KEY_LOCATION` variable. Do you mean it's `"City, state"`?

Comment: KEY_LOCATION is a String field and the value varies for each row, but always contains a "city, state".  Madison, Wisconsin ... Chattanooga, Tennessee .. San Diego, California  etc

Comment: I'm not asking about the row values. What value is assigned to `KEY_LOCATION`? For example, you likely have a line like `public static final String KEY_LOCATION = ???;`. What comes after the `=`? Or are you saying that you're changing the value of `KEY_LOCATION` somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "LOCATION";

Comment: Hmm. Odd. The `-1` means `getColumnIndex()` couldn't find the given column in the `Cursor`. Try dumping the `Cursor` right after the query line, and see what you get in the logs: `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);`.

Comment: Same error.  Is it possible I just have some random corrupt data in that column?  I could easily uninstall and reinstall.  I'm not sure with that error if its likely to help.

Comment: Yeah, that Exception is still going to happen if you don't comment out or remove the `arrayList.add()` line. We're not interested in that, at the moment. We just wanna see what's in the `Cursor`. Look above the stack trace for that Exception in the logs. You should see many lines that are the contents of the `Cursor`. If you don't see it, comment out the `arrayList.add()` line to reduce the noise, and run it again.

Comment: updated with DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);

Comment: Uh, hmm. I'm kinda stumped. I'm just not seeing why that's throwing, if the code you've posted is exactly as you have it. There aren't any spaces in the `"LOCATION"` value, are there? Also, try changing the `getColumnIndex()` call to `getColumnIndexOrThrow()`, and see what that Exception message has to say. In any case, you could just do `c.getString(0);` there, since you actually know the column index.

Comment: I misspoke there. I know why it's throwing, but not why it can't find the column. What does the `getColumnIndexOrThrow()` Exception message tell you?

Comment: I added the getColumnOrThrow() and the neither the response of the app nor log looked any different to me.  If the exception message was there, I didn't know how to find it.  I did reinstall and it's working (for now).  I am worried that this issue will come back if I have some unresolved issue in my code.

Comment: OK, the Exception message should've changed to something like `IllegalArgumentException: column 'whatever' does not exist`. If it didn't, then it's likely that you were running on "stale" code. Are you using Instant Run? If so, that's almost certainly the issue, and you shouldn't really need to worry about bugs like that, as a complete rebuild will take care of them. Instant Run is a real jerk like that sometimes.

Comment: I am using instant run.  Thank you so much for helping me through this.  "Stumping" you helped me feel better about my approach and that I didn't have some glaring issue. If it doesn't feel like much was accomplished, know that this whole process helped me greatly.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Glad you got it resolved. Cheers!

Comment: The -1 is likely due to `getColumnIndex` being case sensitive. The dump shows location as being lowercase yet you say `KEY_LOCATION = "LOCATION"; `; probably because of a change made without the database being deleted, hence why reinstall fixed the issue.

Comment: OMG!  I did change that from lower case to upper case.  I didn't think it would cause an issue.  Wow!  Great to know.  Add that as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @MikeT That was my first thought, too. In my quick test, `getColumnIndex()` was not case-sensitive. Haven't checked the docs or the sources yet, though.

Comment: @MikeM. well I've just done a test where it was. e.g. table created with `CREATE TABLE friends(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, _name TEXT, _desc TEXT, _residence TEXT, _status TEXT, _key_image BLOB )`. using `csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("_Name"));` gives -1. I've come across this before, if the old grey matter works a little bit. :)

Comment: @MikeT Yeah, I just ran another test with a local database, and it is there. My first test was on a system `ContentProvider`, and it's not for that. Very weird. Seems like it depends on the exact `Cursor` implementation. Which kinds makes sense, now that I think about it.

Comment: @MikeT Yep, found it. The `Cursor` implementation that `ContentResolver` uses [does an `equalsIgnoreCase()` when looking through the column names](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#317). `SQLiteCursor`'s [`getColumnIndex()` method does not](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#165). Jeez. That's what I get for assuming consistent behavior. Sorry about that, seekingStillness. I should not have assumed that.

Comment: @MikeM. hey not your fault, imo it's clearly a bug as it's a contradiction to the common flexibility found throughout SQLite and of course what would/should be excepted of any interface. Of course I'll get beaten by you to answering any similar question in future :)

Comment: @MikeT Well, at least we'll both have a definite answer for that particular discrepancy, should we either ever happen across it. I do like being a little smarter. :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that `getColumnIndex()` can be/is (see comments) case sensitive and thus may return -1 for what should be an acceptable column name.

- ***Clarification of can be/is*** :-
- > The Cursor implementation that **ContentResolver** uses does an
  >   **`equalsIgnoreCase()`** when looking through the column names.
  >   SQLiteCursor's **`getColumnIndex()`** method **does not**.
  >
  > As researched by ***Mike.M.***
  >
  > **Contentresolver**'s **getColumnIndex** :-
  >
  > [android/platform/frameworks/base/master/./core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/database/AbstractCursor.java#317)
  >
  > **SQLiteCursor**'s **getColumnIndex** :-
  >
  > [android/platform/frameworks/base/56a2301/./core/java/android/database/ sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java#165)

In this case the column name was changed from lower to upper case  but the database was not changed (i.e. the cursor dump shows) :-

```
 I/System.out: location=Collegedale, Tennessee ......
```

Whilst the code has :-

```
arrayList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION)));
```

Where as the OP says is defined as :-

```
private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "LOCATION";
```

Thus **`-1`** is returned as `location` is not equal to `LOCATION`.

One fix would be to cause the table to be recreated using KEY_LOCATION as the column name. This could be achieved by re-installing the App or deleting the App's data. (increasing the version may be an option but is dependent upon the code in the `onUpgrade` method.).

Another get-around could be to change :-

```
String[] column = { KEY_LOCATION };
```

to :-

```
String[] column = { KEY_LOCATION + " AS " +  KEY_LOCATION };
```

the actual query would work as the column name in SQLite is case insensitive but the column would be retrieved using the failing column name thus the `gettColumnIndex` would then work.

There are probably 101 other get-arounds.

Answer (score 0):

try this,and there is no need to start transaction.

```
public String[] getLocationColumn(){
   ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
   String[] column = { KEY_LOCATION };
   try{
       Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_TRAILS, column, null, null, null, null, null);
       if (c != null){
           while (c.moveToNext()){
               arrayList.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATION)));
           }
           c.close();
       }
   }
   return arrayList.toArray(new String[arrayList.size()]);
 }
```